# very large CSV Reader application(GUI)

Tags: excel, user-interface, csv

is there a CSV Reader application(GUI) that handles large files? I tried CSVEd, it doesn't handle line terminators correctly.  Excel does the line terminator correctly, however is slow at handling large data.  Are there any other alternatives besides excel?

Comment: What do you want the application to do for you? 
Any half decent programmers editor will easily handle large text files, will have search, macros, sorting and all sorts of things.

Comment: @mattnz: it should behave like excel, renders a gui table grid at the least, not just any half ass text based editor.

Comment: We are not all mind readers, so now we know your requirement is "Is there a faster version of Excel than Excel" you might get an answer to that question. 
However, I doubt that is your requirement. What do you really want to do with the data.

Answer (score 2):

Did you had a look at [OpenRefine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) (formet Google Refine) It offer a nice GUI to filter and manipulate large amount of data.